# on scroll moving the two divs in v shape

Tags: jquery, html, css

As I am new to CSS and jQuery I am trying to learn the different animations. Right now I want to do the animation similar to [domain.me](http://%20domain.me/.).

I am using jQuery's `scrolltop()` to get the position and based on the scroll position displayed in the console using `console.log` I manually added the if statement and `addClass()`. Below is my complete code (style and script in same file)

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2vshjty/)

```js
$(window).scroll(example);

function example() {
  var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log("Scroll from Top: " + tempScrollTop.toString());

  if (tempScrollTop > 20 && tempScrollTop < 50) {
    $("#div1").addClass("slide");
    $("#div2").addClass("slider");
  }
  
  if (tempScrollTop > 50 && tempScrollTop < 100) {
    $("#div1").addClass("slide1");
    $("#div2").addClass("slider1");
  }
  
  if (tempScrollTop > 100 && tempScrollTop < 200) {
    $("#div1").addClass("slide2");
    $("#div2").addClass("slider2");
  }
  
  if (tempScrollTop > 200 && tempScrollTop < 300) {
    $("#div1").addClass("slide2");
  }
};
```

```css
#mainbord {
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("2.jpg");
}

.divv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

.div3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.div4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.slide {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 420px;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
  transition: all 600ms ease-in;
  */
}

.slide1 {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: px;
  height: 160px;
  margin-top: 160px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  transition: all 600ms ease-in;
}

.slide2 {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
  transition: all 600ms ease-in;
}

.slider {
  margin-left: 550px;
  margin-top: background-color:green;
  transition: all 600ms ease-in;
  width: 300px;
}

.slider1 {
  margin-left: 700px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 600ms ease-in;
  width: 250px;
}

.slider2 {
  margin-left: 730px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 600ms ease-in;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainbord">
  <div id="div1" class="divv">
    <img src="1.png" width=100%,height=100%/>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="div2"></div>
</div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove/toggle the CSS class. In your example, the elements has every Class (slide, slide1, slide2) at the end.

Comment: i added class to elements because to use it in addClass() and removeClass() in jquery

Comment: A better solution is possible. But try this in your code:

if (tempScrollTop > 20 && tempScrollTop < 50)  {
        $("#div1").addClass("slide");
        $("#div2").addClass("slider");
        $("#div1").removeClass("slide1");
        $("#div2").removeClass("slider1");
      }

      if (tempScrollTop > 50 && tempScrollTop < 100) {
        $("#div1").addClass("slide1");
        $("#div2").addClass("slider1");
        $("#div1").removeClass("slide2");
        $("#div2").removeClass("slider2");
      }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are familiar with the chrome dev console, [image]

Select the .me icon `<div id ="slikadiv"..` (check the screen shot) and now slowly scroll in the web section, see how CSS properties `width`, `top`, `left` changes for the same.

Write your own function in the `.scroll` jquery function to move the icon.

Also check the other CSS properties too.